# Get Value of HeroCard and display in Carousel

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

May I ask about how to get the value of HeroCard after selected?

And

Display the Hero Card in Carousel Format?

Here with my Source code and Screenshot(display in Emulator).

```
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(content);
        var stopNames = jObj.SelectToken("legs[2].stops.stopName");
        var stopIds = jObj.SelectToken("legs[2].stops.stopId");
        JArray stops = (JArray)jObj.SelectToken("legs[2].stops");


        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        foreach (JToken stop in stops)
        {
            stopIds = (string)stop.SelectToken("stopId");
            stopNames = (string)stop.SelectToken("stopName");

            var reply = MessageFactory.Carousel(new Attachment[]
           {
                new HeroCard(
                    //title: stopIds.ToString()+ stopNames.ToString(),
                    buttons: new CardAction[]
                    {
                        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: stopNames.ToString() , value: stopIds.ToString())
                    }

                    ).ToAttachment()
           }
           );
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);


        }
```

Screen Shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the hero cards in a carousel format, you only have to add multiple hero cards to the carousel.

For example:

```
var reply = MessageFactory.Carousel(new Attachment[]
        {
            new HeroCard(
                //title: stopIds.ToString()+ stopNames.ToString(),
                buttons: new CardAction[]
                {
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "title1" , value: "value1")
                }

                ).ToAttachment(),
              new HeroCard(
                //title: stopIds.ToString()+ stopNames.ToString(),
                buttons: new CardAction[]
                {
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "title2", value:"value2")
                }

                ).ToAttachment(),
                new HeroCard(
                //title: stopIds.ToString()+ stopNames.ToString(),
                buttons: new CardAction[]
                {
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "title3", value:"value3")
                }

                ).ToAttachment()
        }
        );
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

And in Your case, since you are using **CardAction** of type **ActionTypes.ImBack**

The **Value** is being sent as the **text** and you can get that by doing the following:

```
var value = turnContext.Activity.Text
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment on how to send a carousel from a foreach loop.

try the following:

```
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(content);
        var stopNames = jObj.SelectToken("legs[2].stops.stopName");
        var stopIds = jObj.SelectToken("legs[2].stops.stopId");
        JArray stops = (JArray)jObj.SelectToken("legs[2].stops");

        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        foreach (JToken stop in stops)
        {
            stopIds = (string)stop.SelectToken("stopId");
            stopNames = (string)stop.SelectToken("stopName");


            var herocard = new HeroCard(
                 //title: stopIds.ToString()+ stopNames.ToString(),
                 buttons: new CardAction[]
                 {
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: stopNames.ToString() , value: stopIds.ToString())
                 }

                 ).ToAttachment();

            attachments.Add(herocard);


        }
        var reply = MessageFactory.Carousel(attachments);

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

What you have to do is first make a list of attachments, and then dynamically add into it from inside the foreach loop, the Carousel should be outside the foreach loop since you need to send **ONE** carousel that contains **MULTIPLE** cards

Comment: but weird is cant display Carousel in Bot Framework Emulator & Web Chat

Comment: The example i gave you was displayed correctly as a Carousel ( Horizontal )

Comment: May I ask about how to display vertical

Comment: A carousel is displays cards horizontally, if you want to display multiple buttons vertically in a single card i can show you an example how to do so, but there isn't a "vertical carousel" not that i know off at least, You might be able to do a "vertical carousel" using Adaptive cards

Comment: I had update my source code , I need to it to display Horizontal. is that my HeroCard put wrong place?

Comment: I can't see the code for those 3 buttons, you are showing the code for only 1 button

Comment: I Grab the data from JSON, so its need for loop or for each loop to display in Bot. Here with the sample JSON https://github.com/cheahengsoon/AzureMapsBotBuilder/blob/master/Travel.json